# get value from the list when check box is clicked

Tags: angular, ionic2

i have a list with checkbox, when i check a checkbox i need the selected item to be displayed on click of done button

```
 <ion-list *ngFor="let item of options" style="margin-bottom: 0px">
        <ion-grid>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-checkbox ></ion-checkbox>
                <ion-col>
                    <ion-label style="margin-bottom: 0px;  margin-top: 0px;">{{item.val}}</ion-label>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
    </ion-list> 
    <button (click)="done()" >done</button>

done(){
        console.log("done");
        /*here  i need to get the values of the items that are selected*/
    }



public options =    [{
                        "val" : "United States"                          
                    },
                     {
                        "val" : "Afghanistan"
                    },
                     {
                        "val" : "Albania"
                    },
                     {
                        "val" : "Algeria"
                    },
                     {
                        "val" : "American Samoa"
                    }]
```

"options is an array of items"
Could someone help me to get only the selected values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
checkboxes:boolean[];

constructor(){
  this.checkboxes = this.options.map(v => false);
}

done(){
  console.log("done");
  var result = []; 
  this.options.forEach(
      (val, idx) => result.push({item: val.val, checked: this.checkboxes[idx]}));
  console.log(result);
}
```

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let item of options; let i=index" style="margin-bottom: 0px">

  ...
  <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="checkboxes[i]" ></ion-checkbox>
```

Comment: this makes all items in the list checked i need only specific items in list

Comment: I don't see why it would. You could try `this.checkboxes = this.options.map(v => false);` instead of `new Array (...);` Ensure you have this line after `this.options` is initialized.

Comment: now i could get, instead of Boolean how could i get that item value in that list {{item.val}}

Comment: `var result = []; this.options.forEach(val, idx => result.push({item: val, checked: this.checkboxes[idx]}));`

Comment: err with val could not find name

Comment: The Plunker uses the code from your updated question already ;-)

Comment: this return all object could i get only the objects that are in true state

Comment: This code `result.push({item: val.val, checked: this.checkboxes[idx]})` builds the result, you can change it to meet your requirements. For example `result.push(val.val)`. If you want such concrete answers, please next time add to the question the exact details how you want the result look like.

Comment: sorry what i am asking is, if i check 1st box i need the object of that 1st box, i dont want the object with false to be displayed

Comment: And when the 1st and the 3rd are selected?

Comment: only the 1st and 3rd object, whatever object is true that object alone should be dispplayed

Comment: If you want the whole object, not only the name, then use `result.push(val)`

Comment: i get like this  [true, false, false, false, false], i need [checked: true, val: united states] and same for any item that is true

Comment: `[checked: true, val: united states]` is not possible, the code in my answer above returns the closest you can get to that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137123/discussion-between-yokesh-varadhan-and-gunter-zochbauer).